# C++ Unable to Print the Data in Pointers of a Linked List after I've Traversed the List without Adding a Node

Tags: c++, linkedin-api, nodes

I'm dealing with a doubly Linked List. It's made up of classes and is centered around the current node (instead of a node in the beginning or end of the list). Now my print function will throw an error but only if I have traversed the list at all. My print function just prints data in the current node (providing it's not null). Here's my print function: (much more detailed description of my file hierarchy and code at the bottom)

```
void queue::print(){
    if (current){
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "+++++++++++++++++++ Webpage +++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl
            << "URL: " << current->data.getURL() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl 
            << "Title: " << current->data.getTitle() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl
            << "Content: " << current->data.getContent() << std::endl
            << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << std::endl << "Your not on a page. Please navigate to a page first." << std::endl;
    }
```

Now, if I've filled the list with two nodes of data, and I execute my print function, it'll print the data in the node just fine. However, if I traverse  to the previous node with my goBack() function:

```
void queue::goBack(){
    if (!current->previous){
        std::cout << "No previous page to go to!" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        temp2 = current;
        current = current->previous;
    }
}
```

That will execute fine, but when I try to print the data in the node (with the same print function) I receive this error:

[image: Error Message]

and visual studio opens up a file without an extension type, with what looks like C code in it, called xstring, which has a break arrow pointing to line 1754 on it.

Now let me explain my code in a little more detail. I have five files: webQueue.h, webQueue.cpp, webPage.h, webPage.cpp, & main.cpp. All of the functions I've listed are in my webQueue.cpp file.

Here's webQueue.h:

```
#include "webPage.h"
class queue{
public:
    queue();
    void newPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c);
    void goForward();
    void goBack();
    void print();
private:
    struct Node{
        webPage data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };
    Node* temp;
    Node* current;
    Node* temp2;
};
```

And here's webPage.h:

```
#include <string>
class webPage{
public:
    webPage();
    webPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c);
    std::string getURL();
    void setURL(std::string u);
    std::string getTitle();
    void setTitle(std::string t);
    std::string getContent();
    void setContent(std::string c);
private:
    std::string URL;
    std::string title;
    std::string content;
};
```

My webQueue.cpp file includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "webQueue.h"
```

My webPage.cpp file just includes webPage.h and my main.cpp file (which contains my executing function) includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "webQueue.h"
```

Although these relations may seem a little convoluted, they should all be valid. The cpp files are linked to their header files with the exact same name (providing the header file exists), along with main.cpp being linked to webQueue.h and webQueue.h being linked to webPage.h. I can't see what I'm doing wrong with my code—although that's probably just because I'm having such a hard time understanding exactly how pointers work. I imagine that the error is in the code of my print(), goBack(), and goForward() functions (although I can't test my goForward() funtion until I fix my goBack() function) but I can't tell what's wrong.

Any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated, as I am stumped. Here's a dropbox link to all the files so that you can test this program for yourself and see if I have any other functions with errors: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yekrz6dln1v9npk/webQueue.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Your `queue::newPage` function doesn't initialise the `previous` node when it adds a new page, which means the first node's `previous` points to random garbage. You need to set this to `nullptr` (preferable your `Node` structure should have a constructor that does this automatically).

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. That's an error I've made twice before! But it doesn't fix the issue. ಠ~ಠ

Comment: Also, how do I initialize the nodes within the struct in my class in a default constructor?